# Modify Script to make Teachers with same EventId which are in different rows in 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**This is my initial table:**

```
 EventId | StartDate |Category |Event Name | Teacher | Paid  | PayTier
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Franco    1000    Tier 1 
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Jeff      1000    Tier 2
  1        10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello       Azeem     1000    Tier 3
  2        10/18/1995  MND       Bye         Rafa      15      Tier 2
  2        10/18/1995  MND       Bye         Ben       15      Tier 2
  3        10/19/1995  LMD .     Go .        Zoe       32      Tier 4
  4        10/20/1995  SND .     Zed .       Claudia   68     Tier 1
```

My Goal: make rows with the same EventId a single row BUT ALSO have the teachers listed in the row like: Franco,Jeff,Azeem (e.g. for EventId 1)

**The result should be like this for example:**

```
EventId | StartDate |Category |Event Name | Teacher     | Paid | Tier of Pay
   1     10/16/1995  Retreat   Hello   Franco,Jeff,Azeem  1000  Tier 3
```

Currently I have this script. It solved the first part of my problem - that EventId 1 was now in a single row. The problem now is that it only shows 1 of the teachers (e.g. only Franco when it should show Franco,Jeff,Azeem)

**The current script:**

```
SELECT top(1) WITH TIES
    a.eventId AS [Event_ID],
    FORMAT(b.eventStartDate, 'd') AS [Start Date],
    dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR)) AS Categories,
    b.EventName AS [Event Name],
    d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName AS Teacher,
    b.spacesAvailable AS Paid,
    FORMAT(SUM(a.discountAmount), 'C') AS Scholarships,
    FORMAT(SUM(a.Donation), 'C') AS [Tier of Pay],
CASE WHEN d.Pay_Tier = 'Tier 1' THEN '85' 
    WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 2' THEN '96' 
    WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 3' THEN '107'
    WHEN Pay_Tier = 'Tier 4' THEN '117'
    ELSE SUM(a.totalpaid)*0.4
END AS Pay_rate
FROM dbo.RetreatSuiteRegistrations a
JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEvents b ON a.EventId = b.EventId
    AND a.registrationStatusId = 1
    AND b.spacesAvailable > 0
JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteEventAttributes c ON a.EventId = c.EventId
    AND c.attributeName = 'EVENT_CATEGORIES'
JOIN (SELECT t1.attributeId,
            t1.EventId,
            i.EVENT_TEACHERS
        FROM @attribute_table                                    t1
        OUTER APPLY dbo.teacherstring3(t1.EVENT_TEACHERS, '|') i ) AS MyTest ON a.EventId = MyTest.EventId
JOIN dbo.RetreatSuiteTeacher d ON MyTest.EVENT_TEACHERS = d.TeacherID
GROUP BY a.eventId,
    b.eventStartDate,
    dbo.CategoryString(CAST(attributeValue AS VARCHAR)),
    b.EventName, d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName,
    d.Pay_Tier,
    Pay_rate
ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by a.eventId order by d.Pay_Tier desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about where to include in your script, but you can get you desired output as you have mentioned in this way as well.

```
`Select 1 as EventID,  convert(date,'10/16/1995', 110 ) as Startdate,   'Retreat' as 
Category,    'Hello' as [Event Name],        'Franco'  as Teacher,    1000 as Paid,   
'Tier 1' as Paytier 
into #temp
union all  
Select 1 as EventID,  convert(date,'10/16/1995', 110  ) as Startdate,   'Retreat' as 
Category,    'Hello' as [Event Name],        'Jeff'    as Teacher,  1000   as Paid,   
'Tier 2' as Paytier union all 
 Select 1 as EventID,  convert(date,'10/16/1995', 110  ) as Startdate,   'Retreat' as 
 Category,    'Hello' as [Event Name],        'Azeem'   as Teacher,  1000   as Paid,   
'Tier 3' as Paytier union all 
 Select 2 as EventID,  convert(date,'10/18/1995', 110  ) as Startdate,   'MND'     as 
 Category,    'Bye'   as [Event Name],        'Rafa'    as Teacher,  15     as Paid,   
'Tier 2' as Paytier union all 
 Select 2 as EventID,  convert(date,'10/18/1995', 110  ) as Startdate,   'MND'     as 
 Category,    'Bye'   as [Event Name],        'Ben'     as Teacher,  15     as Paid,   
 'Tier 2' as Paytier union all 
 Select 3 as EventID,  convert(date,'10/19/1995', 110  ) as Startdate,   'LMD'     as 
 Category,    'Go'   as [Event Name],         'Zoe'     as Teacher,  32     as Paid,   
 'Tier 4' as Paytier union all 
 Select 4 as EventID,  convert(date,'10/20/1995', 110  ) as Startdate,   'SND'     as 
 Category,    'Zed'  as [Event Name],         'Claudia' as Teacher,   68    as Paid,   
 'Tier 1' as Paytier  `
```

Query: For XML path will work like string aggregation (if you are using SQL server 2017 you can use string agg function as well)

```
SELECT EventID, startdate, category,[Event Name] , paid, max(paytier) paytier ,
Teacher = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + cast(Teacher as varchar(100)) FROM #temp t1 where t1.EventID = t.EventID  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
           )

FROM #temp t GROUP BY EventID, startdate, category,[Event Name] , paid
```

Output:

```
  EventID   startdate   category    Event Name  paid    paytier     Teacher
   1       1995-10-16   Retreat     Hello       1000      Tier 3    Franco,Jeff,Azeem
   2       1995-10-18   MND         Bye          15       Tier 2    Rafa,Ben
   3       1995-10-19   LMD         Go           32       Tier 4    Zoe
   4       1995-10-20   SND         Zed          68        Tier 1   Claudia
```

Comment: Could you please show how the Query with the XML path will fit into my query (the long one) as that is the query I am using to make the initial table I showed.

Comment: The column 'Teacher' in my script is the  d.FirstName + ' ' + d.LastName.

Comment: I think it should fit where you are taking first name + Last name I assume but doing with sub query will be more easier I think after you get your all the values in your select list and then applying for xml

Comment: do you think you could edit my Query and add it in where you think it could go? I keep trying but am getting many syntax errors and things. Would be much appreciated if you gave it a go.

Comment: If OP uses SQL SERVER 2017 then the new [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function can be used instead of XML "trick"..